# Conditionally replace column data over a range of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select a range of rows (done) and conditionally replace the values in a column. How best to perform this

`df.loc[ (df['Time'] > 80) & (df['Time'] < 120) ]`

This successfully provides the locations over a given time range. What I need need todo is within this range replace instances of '00' with 'FF' in the Vel column

I could iterate over but is there are more pandas friendly way to perform this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 possible solutions - `replace` by match only this condition:

```
m1 = (df['Time'] > 80) & (df['Time'] < 120)
#alternative
m1 = df['Time'].between(80, 120, inclusive=False)

df.loc[m1 , 'Vel'] = df.loc[m1 , 'Vel'].replace('00','FF')
```

Or set values with chained another condition for match `00`:

```
m1 = (df['Time'] > 80) & (df['Time'] < 120)
m2 = df['Vel'] == '00'
df.loc[m1 & m2, 'Vel'] = 'FF'
```

Comment: Fantastic! I havn't quite gotten my head around how to merge data back into a df after a manipulation. I could do the replace (with df.replace), I could do the filtering... I just could not figure out how to combine.